# After Browsing another web page the expiration of cookie show N/A in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, setcookie

I have set the post count in codeigniter by using this code ..

```
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $check_visitor = $this->input->cookie(urldecode($vbslug), FALSE);
        $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
        if($check_visitor == false) 
        {
          $this->input->set_cookie(urldecode($vbslug),"$ip",3600);
          $this->mymodel->increase_views_of_post($vbslug);
        }
```

In above code the $vbslug is url of my Website post.

There is no problem in setting the cookie, it shows expiration of 1hr and value which is my ip, but the problem is that whenever I browse another post  in my website the expiration of that url shows N/A.

[See this first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1PdR.png)

'kanchan-studio-sh' url having a expiration of 1hr, but when I browse another page.

[see this second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkzRw.png)
'kanchan-studio-shakarpur' having expiration N/A.

I don't what I have done wrong in my code.

Comment: where is the code to echo N/A? further lets say a user browses 10-20 pages... that's 10-20 cookies. you would be better off with a database-based implementation for *everything* or to simply use google analytics to track the pageview for you pushing the path along with the tracking data. then you can easily retrieve the analytics data. this also allows you more options in terms on analyzing later on.

Comment: Hii.. Alex I have updated my question please check it out

Comment: i guess what i would do is to clear my cookies, everything, and then refresh the page so it sets the cookie then check to see if the cookie still has the valid expiration, and do this a few times just to make sure that other project cookies aren't affecting it. then report back

Comment: No alex it's not working.. I have cleared my cookies, but the issue is again same

Comment: and you checked by only accessing one post right? not trying a few. cuz i just wanted to see if multiple cookies was somehow causing it.

Comment: see the screen shot of dev tools which i have taken.. all the previous url expiration set N/A

https://imgur.com/a/mIYtpAE

Comment: i get that. im saying that you should clear everything and just test *one* page (same slug) to rule out multiple cookies being an issue somehow. if that isn't the case I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Please see this.. I have taken a screen shot. the url is 'photo-tantra'
https://imgur.com/a/MNPqbCO